# How can I run Photocollage on ubuntu 21.10?

Tags: python, gtk, image-processing, 21.10

Photocollage makes a bigger combined image from a number of specified inputs. Maybe not a straightforward program, but it used to work. Now, under Ubuntu 21.10 it segfaults immediately.

The program is a simple Python script, that bails out on this line:

```
from photocollage import gtkgui
```

I'm far from a Python expert, so I don't know what's missing. Previously it just ran as it was, but not now.

Anyone who knows? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the problem exactly?  Are you trying to install the software? There is a package `photocollage` in Ubuntu repos so you can get it easily from the software center or by using apt

Comment: @Nmath Package ```photocollage``` is installed, so that is not the problem. Why Python segfaults when I import ```gtkgui``` from it is the mystery.

Comment: Please make your question more reproduble. On my 21.10 VM I can install `photocollage` [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/photocollage) and `python3 -c "from photocollage import gtkgui"` does not crash.